# How are Google Cloud Firestore rules managed without Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've added Firestore to a project in my Google Cloud console but I don't see a way to manage rules.  All documentation points to Firebase but my project wasn't started in Firebase.  Thought I might be able to deploy/manage the rules via the Firebase CLI but it doesn't recognize my GCP project on `firebase init`.

Comment: Have you tried using the Firebase console?  You should be able to add any Firebase to any Cloud project that way.  https://console.firebase.google.com

Comment: I have but I don't see my GCP project listed there.

Comment: If you're just expecting it to appear, that's not going to be sufficient.  https://medium.com/google-developers/whats-the-relationship-between-firebase-and-google-cloud-57e268a7ff6f

Comment: Ah.  I didn't notice that the `Project name` field in the `Add a project` dialog was a dropdown.  Thanks!  If you want to leave an answer, I'll mark as such.

Comment: FYI security rules won't be relevant to your project unless you're accessing Firestore using the Firebase SDKs in a mobile app.  If you're using a server SDK, security rules won't apply.

Comment: Right.  Rules only apply to [mobile (and web) clients](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add Firebase services to an existing Google Cloud project via the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).  A more detailed explanation of the relationship between Firebase and Google Cloud can be read about [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/whats-the-relationship-between-firebase-and-google-cloud-57e268a7ff6f).  Once you add Firebase to a Cloud project, you should be able to manage security rules in the console, and also through the Firebase CLI.